# input a math operation in c++ using cin function

Tags: c++, input, operators, cin

Here is a very basic program that simulates a log x(y) function.

I would like to know if it is possible to input a mathematical operation in the cin function.

For example to calculate log2(1/8) ? 
So input 2 for x
and 1/8 for y

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
double x(0.0);
double y(0.0);

cout << "log" << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "result" << endl;
cin >> y;

double loga = log(y) / log(x);

cout << "log" << x << "(" << y << ") =" << loga << endl;

cout << loga << "^" << x << "="<< pow(x, loga)<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: No, I/O functions will not perform math. You need to write your own calculator that reads it as a string, parses it, and performs the math.

Comment: Like @Barmar said, you can't do that directly. Read in the string, tokenize it and parse it.

Comment: `switch(char_read_from_cin)` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

No, `cin` cannot do that. You would have to read the expression as a string, then parse it and evaluate it to a number.

Resources on how to do this for simple cases are easily found online and there are powerful libraries that can do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if it is possible to input a mathematical operation in the cin function.

It's only possible by means you write your own parser, that translates the input achieved from `std::cin` or any other `std::istream` source that isn't covered from any standard translations like `int`, `long`, `float`, `std::string` etc.

Do you should provide logic to parse the input you get and translate that to values and function call logic.

Answer (score 1):

`cin` doesn't support your intent. However, you can follow an approach that hold your fractional expression in a string than convert it as double value. So go on.